# SQLCMD variables not reflecting in SQL from publish profile xml

Tags: csproj, sqlcmd, dacpac, azure-synapse

I have a `dev.profile.xml` file that i use to set environment level values for building the dacpac etc. I defined a sqlcmd variable in this publish profile as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <!-- <IncludeTransactionalScripts>True</IncludeTransactionalScripts> -->
    <DeployScriptFileName>deploy.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
    <ExcludeUsers>True</ExcludeUsers>
    <ExcludeLogins>True</ExcludeLogins>
    <ExcludeDatabaseRoles>True</ExcludeDatabaseRoles>
    <CreateNewDatabase>False</CreateNewDatabase>
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>False</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
    <DropObjectsNotInSource>False</DropObjectsNotInSource>
    <DoNotDropLogins>True</DoNotDropLogins>
    <DoNotDropUsers>True</DoNotDropUsers>
    <DoNotDropRoleMembership>True</DoNotDropRoleMembership>
    <DoNotDropApplicationRoles>True</DoNotDropApplicationRoles>
    <DoNotDropDatabaseRoles>True</DoNotDropDatabaseRoles>
    <DoNotDropPermissions>True</DoNotDropPermissions>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=xxxx;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Integrated Security=False;Trusted_Connection=False</TargetConnectionString>
    <TargetDatabaseName>xxxx</TargetDatabaseName>
    <TargetResourceGroup>xxxx</TargetResourceGroup>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <SqlCmdVariable Include="ADLSSeedLocation">
      <DefaultValue>abfss://staging@xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net</DefaultValue>
      <Value>abfss://staging@xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net</Value>
    </SqlCmdVariable>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And Im using this variable to create a `External Data Source` as below :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [AzureDataLakeStorage]
    WITH (
    TYPE = HADOOP,
    LOCATION = N'$(ADLSSeedLocation)',
    CREDENTIAL = [dummycreds]
    );
```

But each time I run build, driftreports etc , Im getting below warning and error :

```
*** The following SqlCmd variables are not defined in the target scripts: ADLSSeedLocation.
```

Answer (score 0):

`each time I run build` the first place where variable has to be defined is Project properties (sqlproj).

[image]

Build and Schema compare do not use publish.xml: there can be multiple publish configuration files and they are used for **publishing**, not for building. Note, when you publish from VS you use specific publish.xml file, when publishing from command line you pass specific publish.xml file path to sqlpackage.exe

After defining variable in sqlproj it can be imported into any publish.xml with "Load variables" button in Visual Studio SSDT publish dialog.